# Firebase runTransaction() Typing in Dart

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am seeking help with typing of a Firebase Realtime Database transaction within dart.

Specifically I am trying to work through the example transaction code from firebase

```
  void transactions_updatingDataWithTransactions() {
    // [START transactions_updating_data_with_transactions]
    final sfDocRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
    db.runTransaction((transactionObj) async {
      final snapshot = await transactionObj.get(sfDocRef);
      final newPopulation = snapshot.get("population") + 1;
      transactionObj.update(sfDocRef, {"population": newPopulation});
    }).then(
      (value) => print("DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!"),
      onError: (e) => print("Error updating document $e"),
    );
  }
```

The issue arises from the argument of db.runTransaction() is Transaction Function(Object?) transactionHandler

Which in the above, transactionObj is the object. When trying to perform any operations such as

```
      final snapshot = await transactionObj.get(sfDocRef);
```

I get errors that "get" isn't defined for Object?. How do I get around this typing?

The RTDB documentation does not have flutter code see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#go_9)

And the Firestore documentation is the one I am basing this off of see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#dart) because I cannot find any documentation related to the Realtime Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [reference documentation for `Transaction`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Transaction-class.html), is *does* have a `get()` method. But the error message indicates that the compiler thinks that `transactionObj` is of type `Object?`, and that means it doesn't know about its methods.

You can fix this by specifying the type of `transactionObj` in your code. If I recall correctly that should be something like:

```
db.runTransaction((transactionObj: Transaction) async {
```

Alternatively, you can cast `transactionObj` to the correct type in your callback with:

```
db.runTransaction((transactionObj) async {
  final transaction = transactionObj as Transaction;
```

---

The code in your question (e.g. `db.collection("cities").doc("SF");`) is for Cloud Firestore. If you're not using Firestore, it sounds like you're trying to use the wrong API.

To learn about the transaction API for the Realtime Database, see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions

Comment: The specified solution unfortunately does not work. The reference you are using is for Firestore, I am using Firebase's realtime database, who's transaction object does not have a get method. The only methods are "success" and "abort"

Comment: The code in your question (e.g. `db.collection("cities").doc("SF");`) is for Cloud Firestore. If you're not using Firestore, it sounds like you're trying to use the wrong API. --- To learn about the transaction API for the Realtime Database, see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions

Answer (score 1):

realtime database semple

```
/// spariş numarasını getirir


Future<int> getSpNo() async {
    var no = 0;
    await _instence
        .ref(AppDatabaseReferance.sparisNo.value)
        .runTransaction((transaction) {
      no = transaction as int? ?? 0;
      final value = (transaction ?? 0) + 1;
      return Transaction.success(value);
    });
    return no;
  }
```